# How do you add an android bookmark for a webapp using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, bookmarks

Is there a way to create an "Add to homepage" from within an Android web app using JavaScript?

The standard way to do this is complicated:

- Bookmark the page
- Go to the home screen
- Long-press in an empty space to bring up the “Add to Home Screen”
  menu
- select “Shortcuts”
- select “Bookmark”
- choose your bookmark

Thanks-

Comment: Seems there is no simple way to do this on android ( in contrast to iPhone ).  So , we're left with giving users long instructions :(

Comment: Have there been any updates with this?...I would like to do the same with both Android and BlackBerry. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can add a shortcut to your webpage from your webpage as the browser does not recognise the intent scheme which is necessary to perform this.